# Spring-security does not exists AJAX requests (302 error)

Tags: ajax, spring-mvc, spring-security, https, http-status-code-302

I am trying to make an email check for uniqueness. The request is sent via AJAX. And i get **302** error (and i can see this error in browser). I think that my Spring-security does not permit for request and trying redirect to the login-page (when i authorized, i get same error **302**). Why I get **302** error if i permit this request **checkUserEmail**?

Here AJAX-request

```
$("#userLogin").click(function (event)
    {       
        event.preventDefault(); 
            
        var inputValue = document.getElementById("userLogin");
        
        inputValue.addEventListener("input", function (e)
        {
            var request = 
            {
                query: inputValue.value
            };  
                
            $.ajax(
            {
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json",
                url: "checkUserEmail",
                data: JSON.stringify(request),
                dataType: 'json',
                cache: false,
                timeout: 600000,
                success: function(response)
                {                   
                    if (!response)
                    {           
                        alert("This email '" + inputValue.value + "' is already in use.");
                        
                        inputValue.value = "";                  
                    }
                },
                error: function(err)
                {
                    console.log(err);
                }
            });
        })      
    });
```

Here Spring Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/checkUserEmail" }, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<Object> checkUserEmail(@RequestBody AjaxRequest request)
    {
        AD_User currentUser = userService.getCurrentAuthorizeUser();

        String  userEmail   = request.getQuery().toLowerCase();
        boolean result      = true;

        if (userEmail != null && !userEmail.isEmpty())
        {
            if (currentUser == null || !userEmail.equals(currentUser.getEmail()))
            {
                result = userService.getUserByEmail(userEmail).isEmpty();
            }
        }

        return new ResponseEntity<Object>(result, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

Here Spring security (in this code i'm trying disable csrf, but it does not work

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
{
    private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    public SecurityConfig(@Qualifier("userDetailsServiceImpl") UserDetailsService userDetailsService)
    {
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
    {
        http
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/",
                "/about",
                "/getEventsByCity",
                "/sortEvents",
                "/buyService",
                "/checkUserPhone",
                "/getAllTags",
                "/getAllSpecialisations",
                "/checkUserEmail",
                "/forgotPassword",
                "/restorePassword",
                "/404",
                "/filterSearchEvents",
                "/500",
                "/about",
                "/eventCatalog",
                "/createEvent",
                "/eventStatic/**",
                "/activateAccount/**",
                "/events/**/**",
                "**/checkUserPhone",
                "/serviceCatalog",
                "/service/**/**",
                "/createService**",
                "/createService",
                "/robots.txt",
                "/error",
                "/authorized")
        .permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/resources/**", "/ts/**",  "/fonts/**", "/img/**", "/json/**", "/text/**", "/video/**", "/static/**", "/home/dru/uploads/**",
            "data:image/**", "/images/**", "/php/**",
            "/sections/**", "/css/**", "/js/**", "/static/error/**", "/", "C:/home/phantomjs-2.1.1-windows/bin/**")
        .permitAll()
        .anyRequest()
        .authenticated()
        .and()
        .formLogin()
        .loginPage("/authorized").permitAll()
        .failureUrl("/failure")
        .and()
        .logout()
        .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout", HttpMethod.GET.name()))
        .invalidateHttpSession(true)
        .clearAuthentication(true)
        .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
        .and()
        .csrf().disable().cors();       
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception
    {
        auth.authenticationProvider(daoAuthenticationProvider());
    }

    @Bean
    protected DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider()
    {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        daoAuthenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(SecurityMechanism.passwordEncoder());
        daoAuthenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        daoAuthenticationProvider.setHideUserNotFoundExceptions(false);
        
        return daoAuthenticationProvider;
    }
    
}
```

Here my application.properties (i hide password and some settings in this file by "*")

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/attraction
spring.datasource.username=***
spring.datasource.password=***
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.show-sql=false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL81Dialect

spring.mail.host=smtp.gmail.com
spring.mail.port=587
spring.mail.username=***
spring.mail.password=***
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true

hostname=***

upload.path=***

server.error.whitelabel.enable=true
spring.mvn.throw-exception-if-no-handler-found=true
```

[And at this sreenshot it is my error when i'll trying send AJAX-request (in Java i did not take any error)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p4fLH.png). As you can see First i get 302 error

This is my Exception controller

```
@Controller
public class ExceptionController
{
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ExceptionController.class);
    
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;
    
    @GetMapping("/failure")
    public ModelAndView getFailurePage(HttpServletRequest servletRequest, HttpServletResponse servletResponse, ModelMap model)
    {
        userService.getCurrentAuthorizeUser();
        
        HttpSession httpSession = servletRequest.getSession(false);
        
        if (httpSession != null)
        {
            AuthenticationException ex = (AuthenticationException) httpSession.getAttribute(WebAttributes.AUTHENTICATION_EXCEPTION);            
            
            if (ex != null)
            {
                model.addAttribute("showLoginForm", "login");
                model.addAttribute("exceptionMessage", "Bad credentials");
                        
                return new ModelAndView("authorized", model);
            }
        }

        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/error/" + ErrorPages.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR_500, model);          
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/error")
    public RedirectView getErrorPage(RedirectAttributes attr, HttpServletResponse servletResponse)
    {
        AD_User currentUser = userService.getCurrentAuthorizeUser();
        
        attr.addFlashAttribute("flashAttribute", currentUser);
        
        if (servletResponse.getStatus() == 404)
        {
            return new RedirectView("/error/" + ErrorPages.NOT_FOUND_PAGE_404);
        }
        
        return new RedirectView("/error/" + ErrorPages.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR_500);
    }
    
}
```

This is my Exception Handler

```
@ControllerAdvice
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class ExceptionHandlerFilter extends GenericFilterBean
{

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException
    {
        try
        {
            chain.doFilter(req, res);
        }
        catch (RequestRejectedException e)
        {
            HttpServletRequest  request  = (HttpServletRequest) req;
            HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;

            response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND);
        }

    }
}
```

What prevents me from sending an AJAX request?

I tried disabling csrf, but it didn't help. I also tried with sef enabled to transmit with the _csrf.token request in the AJAX request header, but there was a 403 error.